# Pandas - Dataframe - Export to CSV - Alignment Issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm trying to read an excel with multiple sheets, parse it through a data frame, do some manipulation and finally save each sheet as a separate CSV file. Everything works but for writing file into different CSV files, the alignment is horrible when i export it.I mean a single cell gets spilled over to its following columns.

The data in the column is

*** ALARM 959 A3/APT ""ALPBSC1_G10B_IP""U 160829 0100
RADIO TRANSMISSION IP GB INTERFACE FAULT
NSEI   RIP               PORT   REASON
20151  xx.xx.xx.xxx      20151  NS-ALIVE TIME OUT
END"**

But when I export it to CSV it gets split across several column, I tried both comma separated and tab separated but the data from the columns moves across to four others columns as below,

ALARM 519 A3/APT ""ALPBSC1_G10B_IP""U 160829 0000
RADIO TRANSMISSION IP GB INTERFACE FAULT
NSEI   RIP               PORT   REASON
20151  xx.xx.xx.xxx      20151  NS-ALIVE TIME OUT

But when i write into individual excel using **to_excel** function, it works like a charm. I dont think the issue is with a delimiter in that big string as the split isnt between any special character. Am I missing something?

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('MyFile.xls')
d = xl.sheet_names # see all sheet names
for x in d:
    print x
    df2 = xl.parse(x)
    df3 = df2.drop(df2.columns[[0]],axis=1)
    filename = "C:/d/" + x + ".csv"
    df3.to_csv(filename, sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
    #df2.to_excel(filename, index=False) #This statement works
```

Comment: What do you mean by alignment? Exporting to? Since I don't know exactly what is your issue, but I think this might help:

Comment: df3.to_csv(filename, sep='\t',encoding='utf-8',index=False) CSV by default doesn't have any alignment but you can set it in Excel check http://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel

Comment: csv doesn't have any aliment, if you needs the csv to be aligned , then it needs to aligned by adding spaces to data before writing to csv

Comment: Could you post the first 3-4 rows of your CSV to see what alignment means? Thx!

Comment: Are you sure it is an issue with pandas and not the csv viewer (i.e. excel), try opening in notepad or something like that to see if it is really exported incorrectly

Comment: No it isn't a problem with excel. I tried opening it in Notepad ++ , by enabling end of line symbol visible, and it was split at the exact same position along with <CR LF> symbol

Comment: Screenshot here

https://s16.postimg.io/ckmjnomh1/error.jpg